# email issue in jenkins

Tags: email, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want jenkins to send mail if an error occurs during build . Here I have added the post stage and provided the smpt server details in jenkins config .In the console it shows sending email but I am not recieving any mail.
Following is my piplenine script

```
stages {
.........................
}
post {
    success {

      emailext (
          subject: "SUCCESSFUL: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]'",
          body: """<p>SUCCESSFUL: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]':</p>
            <p>Check console output at &QUOT;<a href='${env.BUILD_URL}'>${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]</a>&QUOT;</p>""",
          to: 'myname@abcd.com'
        )
    }

    failure {
     
      emailext (
          subject: "FAILED: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]'",
          body: """<p>FAILED: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]':</p>
            <p>Check console output at &QUOT;<a href='${env.BUILD_URL}'>${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]</a>&QUOT;</p>""",
          to: 'myname@abcd.com'       
        )
    }
  }
```

following is the console output:

```
Stage "Deploy" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
[Pipeline] emailext
Sending email to: myname@abcd.com
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE
```

the following is the configurations that I  did on jenkins
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try the "Test configuration by sending test-email" under the SMTP configuration field?

Comment: i got it working after I changed my email security settings